# Pandas - How to find the second (nth) smallest value in a datafreame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                    'B' : ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'd'],
                    'dis' : [1,2,3,1,5,6, 2,5,4]})

>>>>    A   B   dis
     0  a   b   1
     1  a   c   2
     2  a   d   3
     3  b   a   1
     4  b   c   5
     5  b   d   6
     6  c   a   2
     7  c   b   5
     8  c   d   4
```

I want to pick only the 2nd smallest value in `dis` column for every unique value in column `A`.

The expected results looks like this:

```
>>>>    A   B   dis
     1  a   c   2
     4  b   c   5
     8  c   d   4
```

Comment: Please provide input and output in text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df.groupby(['A']).nth(1).dropna().reset_index()
```